# Server side rendering for complex enterprise application

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, single-page-application

We are maintaining complicated Java EE application. Hundreds of entities and EJB's, thousands of beans encapsulating the business logic. Hundreds of stored procedures and functions. Very complicated business rules.

The project utilizes custom front-controller type MVC framework and templating engine for server side rendering. Here are some key aspects of the framework:

- View based: Independently navigable views and logical divisions
- Form based: All actions happens via forms. Form often has multiple alternate actions. Same form has a lot of variation for different conditions like the state of the entity, user role and business constraint. Form typically reflects an entity or set of entities, and action is an arbitrary transaction.
- Role based: hide / show views, forms, fields, buttons and other items for certain users. There are dozens of different roles
- Components visibility can be conveniently mapped to boolean type bean method (business rule condition)

I wonder if it would be possible to implement such a system using client side rendering. It would be tedious to manage all this state with javascript for sure. Is the server-side rendering the only reasonable solution here, where as 
SPA is more suited to straight-forward CRUD consoles with smaller scale?

I'm asking to consider the risk of creating a new system as SPA where it could grow such a complicated beast that SPA couldn't keep up and the project eventually fails. I would like to know when should I just go with the server side rendering from the start.

What would be the modern MVC framework to meet those requirements (Our framework is from 2000's)?

Comment: The system that you are mentioning in the question already works, right? You are thinking about refactoring it to SPA?

Comment: No, more like the risk of creating a new system as SPA where it could grow such a complicated beast that SPA couldn't keep up and the project eventually fails. I would like to know when should I just go with the server side rendering from the start.

Comment: If you're established rich company with a lot of funding, go for it, but use Martin Fowler's Microfrontends and Microservices.

If you're a small startup, forget about front-end for God's sake!

What a beautiful Struts architecture you have painted! No way you can make such a monolith in React/Redux or Vue/Vuex, those are SPA toys.